# "onclick" event gets fired automatically

Tags: javascript, events, iife

I have this code that has an `onclick` handler and an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Button clicked"); } 

//btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Now clicked"); };

(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
})();
```

The issue is that the **clickHandler** gets **invoked automatically** after the page loads and **the IIFE isn't invoked**. However, on commenting out line 2, and *un-commenting* out line 3 (the commented out line in the above code), the code works as expected.

The only difference between the two lines is that the 2nd line has no **;** in the end, but the 3rd line has.

Also, if I remove the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and keeping the rest of the code unchanged, the code works fine.

Demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pezpqv

Comment: Add `;` at the end of the second line to fix this.

Comment: @raina77ow I know that putting `;` would fix it. But why is the handler getting invoked automatically?

Comment: Because your statement is not treated the way you think about it - `(function(` is considered a part of the statement started on the second line.

Comment: So how does `(function(` being a part of the second line invokes the handler? And if it does, why doesn't the `console.log("Hello World")` get logged in the console?

Comment: Added the explanation. Remember to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) for more details on how ASI works - and how it doesn't - in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky. Because semicolon is missing in the second line of your code, parser doesn't stop there - and consumes all the tokens it can. In the end, the code's parsed as...

```
btn.onclick = function clickHandler() {
  console.log("Button clicked");
}(
  //btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Now clicked"); };

  function() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
)
();
```

See the difference `()` makes - your function expression is invoked *immediately*. It's funny that ...

`function() { console.log('Hello') }`

... is treated as its parameter value - which is ignored anyway.

After that, result of `clickHandler` is attempted to be reused as a function - but, as it returns `undefined`, JS stops with `(intermediate value)(...) is not a function`.

---

Thought it's a good idea to twist your code a bit - and made the following snippet to illustrate the idea with more, well, drama in it.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log('Now clicked');
  return e;
}
  
//btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Now clicked"); };

(function() {
  console.log('Hi!');
})();
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Show this to your colleagues and ask the same question (why doesn't click handler work here?) if you want to make them a bit... mad. )

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. Thanks for the explanation. :D

Answer (score 1):

You missed a semi column over here

```
btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Button clicked"); } ;
```

Comment: I mentioned that in the question itself. See the 2nd last paragraph.

Comment: The ECMAScript specification has specific rules for automatic semicolon insertion, however in this case a semicolon isn't automatically inserted because the parenthesised expression that begins on the next line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call.                                                                                                              https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in starting code with `(` while the previous line of code does not end with semicolon (`;`). This treats both line of codes to be executed together like:

`}(`

To solve the problem either you have to put `;` at the end of the statemnet or move the IIFE code to the top of your code:

```js
(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
})();
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.onclick = function clickHandler(){console.log("Button clicked"); 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn" >Click</button>
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. But I think you should see @raina77ow 's answer to know what's exactly going on in the code.